# Full Text Search in ERP application - is Apache Lucene\Solr the right choice?

Tags: sql-server, solr, lucene, full-text-search

Im currently investigating the tools necessary to add a fast, full text search to our ERP SAAS application with the aim of providing a single search entry point in the application that could search over the many different kind of objects that compose the domain of the software.

​

The application (a Spring Java web application) is backed by a **Sql Server RDBMS** (usign **Hibernate** as ORM), there are hundreds of different tables, dozens of which (but maybe more) should be searchable (usually there are one or more varchar columns in evenry table that should be indexed/searched).

Think for example of a single search bar where i can search customers, contracts, employees, articles..), this data is also very often updated (new inserts, deletes, updates..)

​

I found this article (www.chrisumbel.com/article/lucene_solr_sql_server) that shows how to connect a Sql Server db with Solr, posting a query example on the database that extracts the data used by Solr during the data import.

Since we have dozens (and more) tables containing the searchable data that means that we should pass for a first step that integrate all the sql queries that extracts this data with Solr, in order to build the index?

Second question: not all the data is searchable by everyone (permissions and ad hoc filters), so how could we complement the full text search provided by Solr with the need of putting in place more complex queries (join on other tables for example) on this data?

​

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly asking for a full blown consulting project :-) But a few suggestions are possible.

**Define Search Result Types:** Search engines use denormalized data, i.e. you won't do any joins while querying (if you think you do, stick to your DB:-) That means you need to do the necessary joins while filling the index. This defines what you can search for. Most people "just" index documents or log-lines, so there is just one type of result. Sometimes people's profiles are included, sometimes a difference is made between results from different source systems where the documents come from, but in the end, there is a limited number of types of search results. And even more, they are nevertheless indexed into one and the same schema (where schemas are very malleable for search engines).

**Index**: You know your SQL statements to extract your data. Converting to JSON and shoveling it into a search engine is not difficult. One thing to watch out for: while your DB changes, you keep indexing, incremental or full "crawl" depends on how much logic you want to add. The most tricky part is to get deletes on the DB side into the index. If its gone, its gone: how do you know there was something that needs to be purged from the index :-)

**Secure Search** Since you don't really join, applying access rights at query time amounts requires two steps. During indexing, write principle (group, user) names of those who may read your search result. At query time, get the user ID and expand it, recursively, to get all groups of the user. Add this as a query filter. Make sure to cache the filter or even pre-compute for all users quite regularly and store it in a fast store (the search index is one place, DB would do too:-) Obviously you need to re-index if access rights change. The good thing is: as long as things only change in LDAP/AD, you don't need to index the data, only the expanded groups of the affected users.

**ad hoc filters** If you want to filter for X, put X as a field into the index. At query time, apply the filter.

Comment: Tnx for your answer, I think i will do a POC using Hibernate Search, since I saw that it integrates Lucene, and takes care of the index updating. I accepted it